# python, issue with for loop and plotting

Tags: python, for-loop, plot

```py
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A=np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0]])
print(A)
print(A.T)
print (A==A.T)


omega_1= np.array ([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
print(omega_1)
def Dialer_Problems(S,N):
  for S in range (0,9): 
   omega_S=(omega_1)*A**(N-1)
  return omega_S

Dialer_Problems(5,10)t1=time.time()

t1=time.time  
for N in range (1,200):
 K=Dialer_Problem(S=5,N=N)
 t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

I would like the last 5 lines of the code return 200 different output as I have a four loop for N ranging between 1 to 200. so I can plot them. However, it returns just one. also how to plot it?)

Comment: Your print statement is outside the for loop.

Comment: Indent it to include it in the for loop. Also, there is a typo in `K=Dialer_Problem(S=5,N=N)` and what is `Dialer_Problems(5,10)t1=time.time()` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code mostly contains typos and indentation errors. Try to run this formatted code.

```
import numpy as np
import time

A=np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0]])
print(A)
print(A.T)
print (A==A.T)

omega_1= np.array ([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
def Dialer_Problems(S,N):
    for S in range (0,9): 
        omega_S=(omega_1)*A**(N-1)
    return omega_S

t1=time.time()
for N in range (1,200):
    K=Dialer_Problems(S=5,N=N)
    t2=time.time()
    print(t2-t1)
```